# Género de derecha/o e izquierda

Tags: uso-de-palabras, género

¿Por qué las palabras *derecha* e *izquierda* (en oraciones como "doblar a la derecha") tienen el género femenino y no el masculino? Y ¿por qué *derecho* (en masculino) significa "recto," pero *derecha* (en femenino) es el opuesto de *izquierda*? Parecen ser conceptos muy distintos, pero se expresan con la misma palabra.

Comment: The same applies in French with droit/droite. My guess it that it's something etymological from Latin or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La diferencia se encuentra en el origen latino (Latin) de la palabra; ***Directus*** Significa Recto o Rígido, de ahí la asociación al lado fuerte o predominante del cuerpo.

*Derecha* entonces es el lugar o la dirección del lado predominante del cuerpo y
*Derecho* mantiene el significado original: Recto.

-**México**- Cuándo el término *Derecho* se asocia a una persona, se refiere a qué parte de su cuerpo es predominante o más hábil, El mismo término se puede también asociar a una persona que es o se desempeña de manera Justa, sin truco, trampa o engaño.

La pregunta no lo incluye pero existen también diferentes significados de la palabra Derecho(a) e Izquierda son relacionadas con posiciones políticas a las que una persona o sociedad pueden permanecer.     Durante la revolución Francesa los términos ***La Droite*** y ***la Gauche*** fueron acuñados dependiendo de dónde se situaban las personas, dependiendo al sector que apoyaban, dentro del parlamento Francés.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que se refiere a "la dirección" y derecha es la forma femenina del *adjetivo*.

Puede ver eso en el [diccionario de la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/derecho)

> "23. f. Dirección correspondiente al lado derecho. Tuerza por la
>   primera a la derecha"

También "derecho" es un *sustantivo masculino* o *adverbio*

(Si entiende inglés, en [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=derecho) tiene buena información.)